# Hiveconf/hivevar: possible to have a dot ('.') in a variable name?

Tags: hive, hiveql, airflow

Is it possible to use a dot in a name of hiveconf variable?

All examples in a [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution) show simple variable names like `a`.

**If yes:**

How do I reference it in HQL script? `select ${hiveconf:airflow.ctx.dag.dag_id} as dag_id;` produces syntax error (while `${hiveconf:abcd}` is ok).

**If no:**

Why does [airflow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org) or [azkaban](https://azkaban.github.io) pass variables to hive scripts like this? Wouldn't the authors know that it's not possible to reference these variables?

`hive -hiveconf airflow.ctx.dag.dag_id=video-plays-adverts -f test-hiveconf.hql`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have checked, this works:

```
set hiveconf:airflow.ctx.dag.dag_id=abc;
hive> select '${hiveconf:airflow.ctx.dag.dag_id}';
OK
abc
Time taken: 0.212 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Probably you forgot about quotes.

Comment: Thanks - it does, but not in my context (adressing the static partition). And the crucial thing is that `hiveconf` behaves like a macro system.

Comment: yes, macro it is. you can still use hiveconf variables but as simple values, not complex expressions in your case. Calculate them in wrapper shell

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there were several compound problems:

1) Hivevars work as a C macro system - when you assign `set a = concat('-', ${hiveconf:var_name})`, content of `${hiveconf:a}` isn't a string, but really a command `concat('-', ${hiveconf:var_name})` which gets evaluated every time you use it.

2) I was using it in static partitions, which only accept literals, so this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE xyz 
PARTITION (year=${hiveconf:y}, month=${hiveconf:m}, week=${hiveconf:w}, day=${hiveconf:d})
```

got translated to this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE xyz
PARTITION (year=<complex expression>, month=<complex expression>, week=<complex expression>, day=<complex expression>)
```

Which is not supported - static partition need literals.

End of story. Seems like there is no way to use 'computed' (`set a = concat(${b}, ${c})`) `hiveconf` variables in places of constant.